# Installing Magento 2 extension via composer.json file

Tags: magento2.2, extensions, composer

I bought an extension on Magento store.On my magento installation, I don't have web setup wizard and when I checked the solution for this it requires to change main config file which I don't have access at the moment.So then I downloaded the extension from Magento store, this time the downloaded zip contains only `composer.json` file. How can I install this extension via `composer.json` file ? Itried to install with composer require with only name of the extension I saw in the `composer.json` file, but it didn't work.I need to install this extension with `composer.json` file.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add required libraries in your magento's root > composer.json file from your modules composer.json file.

After that you need to run `composer update` command.